# Performing selection $(this) in jQuery

Tags: jquery, selector, this, each

I perform `$.each` on `li` tags. `li` tags contain different tags. How do I access tags from the current iteration?

Example code:

**jQuery**

```
$('.list li').each(function () {
   // I tried, but didnt work: $(this).filter(".aside h4 a").html("Hello");
   $(this)._HERE TRYING TO ACCESS CHILDREN_.html("Hello");
});
```

**HTML**

```
<ul class="list">
   <li>
       <div class="aside right">
       <h4><a href="#">I want to change this text on each iteration</a></h4>
   </li>
   <li>
       <div class="aside right">
       <h4><a href="#">I want to change this text on each iteration</a></h4>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 5):

Use `find` method to find elements inside the selected one:

```
$('.list li').each(function () {
   $(this).find("a").html("Hello");
});
```

Answer (score 2):

[.children()](http://api.jquery.com/children/) should do what you are looking for.

Also, close the `div` inside the `li`.

Answer (score 0):

use [find](http://api.jquery.com/find/)

```
 $(this).find("a").html("Hello");
```